# Pause button not working

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am writing a pause button for my game (Game for mobile phones).

My Pause script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PauseScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool paused;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        paused = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))    
        {    
            paused = !paused;
        }

        if (paused)    
        {    
            Time.timeScale = 0;   
        }    
        else if (!paused)    
        {    
            Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
    }

    public void Pause()    
    {
        paused = !paused; 

        if (paused)
        {    
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        }
        else if (!paused)
        {    
            Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And Jump that is written like this `jump = Input.GetButton("Fire1");`

When I touch button my player jumps and the game does not pause.

How I can make my game pause and player doesn't jump?

Comment: Do you have the correct button binding? If you can output some debugging, do this inside of the `if(Input...`. E.g. `Debug.Log()` or change a button color or something.

Answer (score 0):

[Unity Docs: Time.timeScale](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html)

> Except for realtimeSinceStartup, timeScale affects all the time and delta time measuring variables of the Time class.

if you want to actually use `timeScale` you need to use `Time.deltaTime` in your calculations. Like:

```
transfomr.position += Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
```

so, it's not going to magically pause all the scripts. `Update()`, `FixedUpdate()` and all the other `MonoBehaviour` functions will still get invoked normally. also, [read about Time.deltaTime](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedTime.html) if you haven't already.

Comment: Like this?   
        if (paused)
        {

            Time.deltaTime = 0;
        }

Comment: no, you cannot set Time.deltaTime, you can only get it. when you write Time.timeScale = 0 it sets Time.deltaTime to 0 (and also some other variables). So this is one of the reasons you have to use Time.deltaTime.

Comment: you are writing `jump = Input.GetButton("Fire1");` this means somewhere in your code you check for `jump` variable and if it's true you move your player. so there, where you move your player, you should multiply movement by Time.deltaTime. then the player will freeze in air. but if the jumping is Physics based, meaning, you are using Rigidbody to jump and move around, it's not going to work. You would need to set Rigidbody's IsKinematic to true to freeze it.

Comment: For a rigidbody you would adjust `Time.fixedDeltaTime` in relation to timeScale. The Docs suggest `Time.fixedDeltaTime = 0.02f * Time.timeScale;`.

Comment: When I set IsKinematic my player not running, just flow @NikaKasradze

Comment: what do you mean by 'flow'? IsKinematic stops physics simulation and lets your object be controlled only by code. Anyways, i think you should follow up a quick tutorial on using Rigidbodies in Unity and when not to. You'll learn a lot faster.

Comment: When I set IsKinematic my jump = Input.GetButton("Fire1"); stopped working @NikaKasradze

Comment: Look . I want to do one thing, just not jump, when I have pause button.

For jump i have jump script, for pause I have pause script. Maybe I need to make pause in jump script and write that player don't jump when I tap button?